# Invalid identifier in OVER Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ORDEN.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HDC_FEC) AS FILE
      FROM (SELECT HDC_OPP AS numberOperation, HDC_FEC AS SystemDate,ESD_DES AS state,HDC_MTV AS motiveCode FROM HDC
              LEFT JOIN TRM ON HDC.HDC_TRM = TRM.TRM_COD 
              ...
```

and I'm getting an error 'invalid identifier HDC_FEC in OVER clauses. If I replace by *SystemDate* works fine. Why I can't use HDC_FEC instead of SystemDate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the `HDC_FEC` column the alias `SystemDate` in the subquery, so you can only refer to that alias in the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ORDEN.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SystemDate) AS FILE
```

The original underlying table columns are not visible - they are out of scope. You can only see what you have exposed in the subquery.

It isn't clear from what you've shown if you actually need the second level of subquery. If you don't have a `where` clause against the subquery (`where ORDEN.some_col = ...`) then you can move the `row_number()` into the same level of query. You may also need the `partition by` clause, but again it isn't clear. (Perhaps you've incorrectly created the second level of subquery so you can add `group by` when you really want a `partition`...?)

Comment: Last part of my query I use WHERE FILE BETWEEN ? AND ?. Thank you.

Comment: @Chema - that makes sense for the outermost query and a single subquery; but you have two levels of subquery, and I'm not sure the innermost one is needed. Hard to tell from your snippet though.

Comment: I using this query to return pagination result using MyBatis.